# Plotting datetime.time object: "float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'date time.time'"

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, seaborn

I have a pandas data frame of dtype: int64, I then convert it to date time using pd.to_datetime. This gives a date as well as the time of day, I only want to plot a distribution plot of the times of the day. I have tried many different things and keep running into errors, I will post the code of my latest error:

```
type(justTime)
```

This returns 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame' so I know it is a data frame.

```
justTime['ACCESS_TIME'].value_counts()
```

This returns a value_counts list of '2020-08-08 12:44:19.000' type objects, which it calls dtype: int64. Of note is when I do: `type(justTime['ACCESS_TIME'])` it returns 'pandas.core.series.Series'.

Next, I make it a datetime by doing the following:
`justTime['ACCESS_TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(justTime['ACCESS_TIME'])`

If I do the following: `justTime['DE_ID_ACCESS_TIME'].dt.time` it prints a list of just the times; for example "13:04:41" but shows them being of dtype: object.

Therefore, when I try

```
ax = sns.distplot(justTime['ACCESS_TIME'].dt.time)
```

I get the error: "TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.time'"

Essentially I have a data frame of datetime object where I want to plot a distribution plot of just the times, no dates. I want to see around what time of the day these access times are clustering, and I have run into so many problems of how to handle this. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: try `ax = sns.distplot(justTime['ACCESS_TIME'].dt.time.astype(str))`

Comment: When I try that I get the error: "could not convert string to float: "13:04:41". However when I try: ```ax = sns.distplot(justTime['DE_ID_ACCESS_TIME'].dt.hour)``` it works and gives me the dist plot of just the hours. I'm kind of lost of how time-series data works.

Comment: if you only want hour of the day, then use `sns.distplot(justTime['ACCESS_TIME'].dt.hour)` . You can similarly use dt.year, dt.month, dt.day etc here. Seaborn can't plot time object.

Comment: I was able to do that, but what if I want to get more specific and show not just distribution by hour but minute as well?